# Login Screen Freezed 17.04

Tags: 17.04, login-screen, system-settings

I updated Ubuntu 16.04 to 17.04 and now my login screen is freezed with no access to touchpad and keyboard! I opened in grub mode there sudo apt-get update is not working either! What do ido? It is showing unable to unlink read only files /var/lib when i try to update

Comment: Please specify your computer, at least brand name and model. It helps if you also tell us about the graphics chip/card.

Comment: My laptop is dell inspiron 5567 AMD Radeon 4 GB Graphics

Comment: 1. Did you backup the 16.04 LTS system before upgrading? In that case the best option is to restore from the backup ; 2. Otherwise, generally, Dell computers *should* work with Ubuntu. Maybe the graphics is a problem. You can try with the boot option `nomodeset`. The computer is new and powerful ; 3. Maybe you can also try live (booted from USB) with Ubuntu 17.10 ; 4. Finally, before doing 'too much', if you have not already done it, boot from a USB boot drive with 16.04 LTS or 17.10, and backup all personal files (at least the files, that you cannot afford to lose.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. It can help other users, if you describe your solution with some details :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem more recently, when upgrading from 16.04 LTS to 16.04.5. That was a bad idea, the screen began freezing at the session login. So when your new to ubuntu like I am, don't upgrade to a version that isn't stable (LTS) unless you've got time on your hands !

**Option 1** : upgrade from 16.04.5 to 18.04 LTS, the latest stable version.

**Option 2** : Change your display manager (gdm3, lightDM)
=> `sudo dpkg-reconfigure MANAGER`

**Option 3**: If you have random freezing, then make sure you have the right drivers for your graphics card => `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

To upgrade despite the login freeze, do it either as **root** (which you can do by booting into a root shell in recovery mode) or by entering **Ctrl + Shift + F2/F3** when at the login interface and, connecting to your session without the graphical interface (I found that connecting to the WIFI to get the update was easier using this last option).

Hope this helps anyone else that makes the same mistake !